# Update Outlook inbox folder

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-3.0

I would like to update (sync) the inbox folder (send/receive) before running this PowerShell script that gets the e-mails, but I don't know how. Is there a way to do this from powershell?

```
$matchString= "support@blabla.com";
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = New-Object -COM Outlook.Application;
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$inbox.Items | where { $_.SenderEmailAddress -match $matchString } |
    Select SenderEmailAddress,to,subject |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: which version of outlook are you using? beacuse even i am able to run $mapi.SendAndReceive($false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do that:

> $mapi.SendAndReceive($false)

Also, for me I needed to use the Logon method before the SendAndReceive:

> $mapi.logon()

[Check the link for more reference](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/05/outlook-send-receive-programmatically/).

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'SendAndReceive'."

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Is it possible to do the same but for a single mailbox?

Comment: sorry, dont have outlook now, cannot check