# Powershell Interop.Outlook Send and Receive specific mailbox and await async completion

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-5.0

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579666/335366) explains how to refresh a Microsoft Outlook mailbox in Powershell using `$mapi.SendAndReceive()`

I would like to extend the question with:

- How can I use Powershell to refresh a specific mailbox in Outlook? For example, if there are 5 mailboxes and I only wish to refresh one.
- How can I get Powershell to wait for `SendAndReceive()` to complete? According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.sendandreceive) it is an asynchronous method.

Accepted solution must be in Powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get Powershell to wait for SendAndReceive() to complete

The [SyncEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend) event of the `SyncObject` class is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send/Receive group.

```
Dim WithEvents mySync As Outlook.SyncObject 

Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set mySync = Application.Session.SyncObjects.Item(1) 
 mySync.Start 
End Sub 

Private Sub mySync_SyncEnd() 
 MsgBox "Synchronization is complete." 
End Sub
```

> How can I refresh a specific mailbox in Outlook?

A `Send\Receive` group lets users configure different synchronization scenarios, selecting which folders and which filters apply.

Use the `Item` method to retrieve the `SyncObject` object from a [SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobjects) object. Because the `Name` property is the default property of the `SyncObject` object, you can identify the group by name.

The `SyncObject` object is read-only; you cannot change its properties or create new ones. However, note that you can add one `Send/Receive` group using the `SyncObjects.AppFolders` property which will create a `Send/Receive` group called `Application Folders`.

The [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.start) method of the `SyncObject` class begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group.

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
 "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
 syc.Start 
End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, this looks really great but I can't accept it as the correct answer for now, as the question is Powershell specific, not VB...

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages. So, there is no difference between them - the same methods and properties are used. The difference is in the syntax, but you will not find a lot of python developers familiar with OOM.

Comment: Thanks again. I do understand where you're coming from, but the post is tagged Powershell. I have a large project in Powershell and I'm looking specifically for a Powershell solution. Anyone that lands on this page presumably will be looking for the same. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Any Powershell solution will be based on the OOM described.

Comment: Yes, but i can't copy and paste your code into my solution and change a couple of things to make it fit. That is what a large amount of SO users are doing. I will use your example to write my powershell version, then i'll post the answer using powershell and mark it as the correct answer. The post is tagged powershell, not VB. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. I have answered the question marked with the `outlook` tag then.